# Як перекласти "elicitation"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, одним-словом

Шановна спільното, допоможіть! Маємо слово "elicitation" від дієслова зі значенням "витягати", "виявляти", але з емоційним забарвленням: щось штибу "витягати на світ Божий" абощо. Чи є можливість або ідеї, як перекласти "elicitation" одним словом?

Elicitation is asking questions that stimulate people to respond and take the behavior you want.

Дякую.

Comment: З опису незрозуміло, який відтінок має процес, яка його кінцева мета. Це щось негативне на штиб маніпуляції чи навпаки?

Comment: ні, це не негатив. Це саме "видобуток інформації з когось", щось на кшталт "докопатися до істини"

Answer (score 10):

Можна піти іншим шляхом і звернути увагу на мистецтво Сократа, який за допомогою правильних запитань виявляв правильне знання у людині. Це мистецтво називається **майєвтика** (грецькою "повивальне мистецтво"):

> [Майєвтика](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) — (μαιευτική se. Τέχνη — «повивальне мистецтво») запропоноване Сократом мистецтво витягувати приховане в людині правильне знання за допомогою майстерних навідних питань.

Comment: овва, яка цікава штука - дякую! До речі, цікаво, навіщо в українському варіанті цього слова додано "й". Не логічніше було б залишити просто "маєвтика"?

Comment: @РоманКушнарьов, мабуть, тому ж, чому [Майя, а не Мая](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/554/4).

Comment: та я б не сказав. Бо в тій же статті на Вікіпедії подається і з "й", і без нього.

Answer (score 7):

[Зі словника e2u](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=elicitation&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> витяга́ння, вийма́ння; ви́явлення, виявля́ння, ви́яв

Comment: Враховуючи, що в оригіналі йдеться про виявлення талановитих кандидатів рекрутером, можна ще спробувати такі [квазісиноніми](//uk.worldwidedictionary.org/вияв): *ви́раз [талантів кандидатом]*, *про́яв*; трішки метафорично: **ви́лив**, **про́блиск**.

Comment: тут трохи не про те. Тут саме видобуток інформації з когось.

Comment: @РоманКушнарьов, навіть не знаю... [Витягання, видобування, отримування, одержання, діставання](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/749/4)? Викривання/викриття, відкриття, розкриття?

Comment: діставання, до речі, дуже гарний варіант. Дяка, що нагадали.